# Why JPA 2.2 stores java.util.Date as null

Tags: java, ejb, jpa-2.2

I have a Java EE Entity class containing a `java.util.Date` field. The value for this field for some reason is not being stored.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSISTENCE_USER")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "findAllusers",
        query = "SELECT U FROM User u "
        + "ORDER BY u.userId"
),
@NamedQuery(name = "getAUser",
        query = "SELECT U FROM User u "
        + "WHERE u.userId =?1 AND u.password=?2 "
        + "ORDER BY u.userId"
)
})
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 10044331905L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateOfBirth;
............
}
```

Here is a singleton that populates a row in the table:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class DataLoaderSessionBean {
    @EJB
    private LoginRequestSessionBean requestLogin;
    @PostConstruct
    public void createData() {
        try {
            List<User> users = new ArrayList();
            Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            users.add(new User("Joe","Ottaviano",date));
            users.add(new User("Partrick","Tucker",date));
            requestLogin.addUsers(users);
        } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Later when I retrieve and examine the data the date field is null:

```
@Stateful
public class LoginRequestSessionBean {
     @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public void addUsers(List<User> users) throws EJBException {
            users
                .stream()
                .forEach(this::addUser);
    }
    public void addUser(User u) throws EJBException {
        try {
            if (em != null) {
                if (em.isOpen()) {
                    if (u != null) {
                        em.persist(u);
                    } else {
                        throw (new EJBException("NULL user can not be added"));
                    }
                } else {
                    throw (new EJBException("EntityManager is closed"));
                }
            } else {
                throw (new EJBException("EntityManager is NULL"));
            }
        } catch (EntityManagerSetupException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught an Exception: "+ e.getMessag();
            throw e;
        }
    }
public List<User> getUsers() throws EJBException{
        logger.entering(className, "getUsers()");
        List<User> users = null;
        try {
            if (em != null) {
                if (em.isOpen()) {
                    Query q = em.createNamedQuery("findAllusers");
                    users = (List<User>) q.getResultList();
                    for (User user : users){
                        Date d = user.getDateOfBirth();
                        if(d == null){
                            System.out.println("The dob for user "+user.getLasName()+" null);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    throw (new EJBException("EntityManager is closed"));
                }
            } else {
                throw (new EJBException("EntityManager is NULL"));
            }
        } catch (EntityManagerSetupException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            throw new EJBException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return users;
    }
}
```

Any idea how to store values for `java.util.Date`?

Comment: Probably not related, but why is your session bean stateful?  It does not appear actually to maintain any internal state (the `EntityManager` does not count, as it is not private to bean instances).

Comment: Do your container's logs tell you anything useful, either at persistence context startup or when you try to persist or load `User` entities?

Comment: Does the entity's table have a column that is correctly mapped to `User.dateOfBirth`?  If you manually enter data into that column (with the persistence context offline) then can you successfully read it back with your EJB?  When your data loader bean adds entities, does that column receive values (as checked by some means other than your persistence context, such a s a command-line SQL client)?

Comment: Constructors in User class?

Comment: @JOhn Bollinger: Thanks for all the comments. I would need to get back to you in regards to the persistence context offline experiment. Regarding your other question, the session bean chosen stateful for other features that I need to add. The current snippet is not the final version.

Comment: @areus: I thank you immensely. You solved the dilemma. The Date parameter was not stored in the constructor. The code snippet, in my original question, was partial. The entity has many more fields and one fell through the cracks. If you care to make it as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted seems correct. You should check that the constructor in the `User` class sets the `dateOfBirth`  field.